Eventbrite API: Unable to Delete Event
I'm trying to delete an event using the Eventbrite API in Postman, following the steps provided in the documentation. However, when I send the request, instead of deleting the event, it simply retrieves the event details without returning any error.
Here's the endpoint I'm using:
DELETE https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/1021349061537

The event does not have any pending or completed orders.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Has anyone else encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated!
